# How to read RSS feed using jQuery

Tags: web, rss, feed, mixed

How do I parse an RSS feed using JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSS feeds are XML documents, so this article should help you out:

http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-makes-parsing-xml-easy